# How to Index an Image (PIL) type array

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

Say that I have two images concatenate, so that the whole image is shape `(256,512)` like this: [X|X]

I want to be able to do this:

```
from PIL import Image
both_image = Image.open(path)
img_left = both_image[:,:256]
img_right = both_image[:,256:]
```

but `*** TypeError: 'PngImageFile' object is not subscriptable`

To fix it, im writing: `both_image = np.array(Image.open(path))` and using `Image.fromarray()` at the end

Is there a better way to do so, without going from Image type to numpy array back and forth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `Image.crop` and crop `both_image` twice.

From the Pllow documentation:

> Image.crop(box=None)
>
> Returns a rectangular region from this image. The box is a 4-tuple defining the left, upper, right, and lower pixel coordinate.

With the same setup:

```
from PIL import Image
both_image = Image.open(path)
```

Crop the left image, from (0,0) to (256,256):

```
img_left = both_image.crop((0,0,256,256))
```

Cropt the right image,from (256,0) to (512,256):

```
img_right = both_image.crop((256,0,512,256))
```